# two different ip addresses only one works

Tags: tizen, google-nativeclient, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

I have an issue with the Tizen emulator.
He is granting my server app an IP address of the type 10.0.2.15.
I cannot get my other clients to connect to this address.
Meanwhile, when i run the app on tizen web simulator , the simulator grants my app a different IP address 192.168.. , that other clients can connect to.
Same when i deploy my app to a  Samsung Tizen TV. 
I am working with socket Native Client for the connection.

How can i make the emulator take the good IP address?
I have tried modifying vm_launch.xml - not working.
Is bridge the correct way to approach the issue or is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

So far I could understand, tizen tv emulator can use independent IP through the bridged network configuration. Please have a look into [this link](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-emulator/bridged-network-configuration).